# Iterate and process child elements with jquery - proper use of $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jquery to find pairs of elements, take the value of one, process it and make it the value of the next one, rinse and repeat.

```
        $(function() {

                $("div").each(function() {
                var longURL = $(this).attr("href");
                $(this).html("processed "+longURL);
                });

        });

    <div class="long" href="plop"></div>
    <div class="short" href="plip"></div>
    <div class="long" href="plopouze"></div>
```

output is :

```
processed plop
processed plip
processed plopouze
```

So this works, since it selects all the divs, somehow proving that each() can handle multiple objects ; But I fail to understand how to properly select back those `$(this)` objects using a class selector, something like `$(this).(.myclass)` (in this case `$(this).('.short')`) does not work..?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `short` and `long` classes?  Inside the `.each`, `this` would be the current `div`.  Also, `$(this).('.short')` is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if `$(this)` has class **.short** you can use `$(this).is('.short')`.

Comment: Or, `$(this).hasClass('short')`

Comment: Thanks very much guys, it works. But I was sort of hoping for a fastest method, like using `$(this).myclass` without the need for a if statement...?

Comment: As Rocket wrote in his answer you could use `$("div.myClass")` to get only a collection of divs which have the class.

Comment: @xaccrocheur: Take a look at my answer.  You can select only `div`s with the class `short` in the first place, so there would be no need for an if.  `$("div.short").each(`

Comment: Yes Rocket, but I want jquery to get two (not just one) classes, take something from the first and pass it to the next, so I need to first get the two, and then select only one.

Comment: ..And now that I integrated this working piece of code in my php-generated page, it does the job (populate the html) and then the info quickly disappears..? I tried taking my function out of `$(document).ready` but to no avail... I think I'm misunderstanding the whole work-flow, I have a php page, doing thing on the server, and then a jquery header script that does thing on the client side... I can't even check the source of the page, since the content I'm printing on the page disappears after loading!? Is there a way to set some kind of breakpoints ?

Comment: Can't imagine why your content disappears. You can set breakpoints in Firebug.

Comment: Yes I found out [how to set breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721809/debugging-jquery-with-firebug), but I cannot find where to put it since if I put it right on the `$(this).val("new "+newLongURL);` it still works, *and* disappears!? If I put it after of course, it does not execute... Hmm

Comment: OK I found out what happened : I had a body onload(); that printed the div where I printed info in :P. Note to self : Forget about body onload when using `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you only want to select `div`s with a certain class, you can do that.

```
$("div.long").each(function() {
  var longURL = $(this).attr("href");
  $(this).html("processed "+longURL);
});
```

This will only loop over `div`s with the class `long`.

Or, you can use `.hasClass` to see if an element has a certain class.

```
$("div").each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('long')){
    var longURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).html("processed "+longURL);
  }
});
```

This will loop over all `div`s, and then check the class of each one to see if it's `long`.

Comment: +1 for `$("div.long")` I think that's what he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of functions you can look into to select elements with different relationships to $(this)

- To see if your element has a descendant, use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)
- To see if your is something (a class, or element type for example) use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
- For any type of tree traversal, like looking for ancestors, descendants, children or siblings, have a look at this list of [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: `.has()` does not work the way you think it does.  `has()` checks to see if the *descendants* of the element match a selector.  `hasClass()` is probably what you were looking for.